# Issues trying to move JLabel inside JPanel to bottom right hand side JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text

```
JLabel answer = new JLabel(); //create new text for the answer
        answer.setText("50235.226");
        answer.setForeground(new Color(0x00FF00)); //set font color
        answer.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.PLAIN,20));
        answer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        answerPanel.add(answer);
```

My code is above I tried using the setHorizontalAlignment statement for a different jLabel and it worked The only difference is the answer JLabel is inside a panel!!
I tried using different statements like
answer.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM); answer.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
both of them gave me a error

Comment: Start by making use of an appropriate layout manager

Comment: By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout with the components centered. If you want the components aligned on the right, then change the alignment property of the FlowLayout.